# I'm unable to get the log events by clicking on the button in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, button

I tried making two butttons with `onClick` function in Android Studio. But I'm unable to see their status in the log events panel.

Here is the image: [App Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuGlM.jpg)
Here is the code:-

```
package com.example.demoap;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void clickFunction(View view) 
    {
        Log.i("Info", "Congratulations, button pressed!");
    }
    public void clickFunction1(View view) 
    {
        Log.i("Info", "Congratulations,2 button pressed!");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

This is what I get when I run the project and click on the two buttons.

```
20:42   IDE and Plugin Updates: Android Studio is ready to update.
20:42   Gradle sync started
20:43   Project setup started
20:43   Gradle sync finished in 39 s 529 ms (from cached state)
20:43   Source generation ended in 1 s 705 ms
20:45   * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
20:45   * daemon started successfully
20:45   Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
20:45   Gradle build finished in 6 s 81 ms
20:46   Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: The window you have open are the build information, not Logcat. Click Alt+6 (or ctrl+6, I forgot) to open Logcat. Check https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are viewing the correct logs. 
To Open logs.

[image: Enable Logcat from here]

Make sure info logs are being viewed.

[image]